# How do I hide a parent div when child div contains a certain text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, show-hide

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhj85gtr/) of my problem.

I am trying to hide an entire div when a certain text is present. How do I do this with Javascript or Jquery?

I have already tried the ff:

```
$containers = document.querySelectorAll("div.row.word-style.table-border");

for ($container of $containers) {
  if ($container.innerText.includes('Internal Request')) {
    $container.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

But it only hides the div if it's the first one. I have multiple divs like the one on my fiddle.

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 3):

includes does not work in IE. you can use.

```
 <script>

$(document).ready(function() {
//It will hide the parent which child contain only Closed not Closed Case
$(".col-md-1").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Closed";
}).parent().hide();


});

</script>
```

Div elements:

```
<div class="row word-style table-border">
  <div class="col-md-1">Tech assistance Internal Request</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Closed Case</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Normal</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">New</div>
</div>

<div class="row word-style table-border">
  <div class="col-md-1">Tech assistance</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Closed</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Normal</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">New</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Arden, Please check this code it will work. and also will fixed your 'Close Case' problem. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it's easy, just use the parent selector:

```
$('.col-md-1').each(function () {
  if ($(this).text().includes('Tech assistance')) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
})
```

Comment: thank you! just one problem. If the text is "Closed Case" and I wanna hide only those with just "Closed" and not "Closed Case" , is it still possible? Right now it's also hiding those with "Closed Case"

Comment: `if (...includes("Closed") && ! ...includes("Closed Case"))`

Answer (score 0):

Use loop and check for string exist or not using `indexOf` like below.

```js
$('.table-border div').each(function(index, element) {
  if ($(this).text().indexOf("Internal Request") >= 0) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.table-border {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c9cacc;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 73px;
}

.word-style {
  font-family: Roboto-Light;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #6d6e71;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-1 {
  width: 8.33333333%;
}

.col-md-3 {
  width: 25%;
}

.col-md-2 {
  width: 16.66666667%;
}

.col-md-1,
.col-md-2,
.col-md-3,
.col-md-4,
.col-md-5,
.col-md-6,
.col-md-7,
.col-md-8,
.col-md-9,
.col-md-10,
.col-md-11,
.col-md-12 {
  float: left;
}

div {
  width: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row word-style table-border">
  <div class="col-md-1">Tech assistance Internal Request</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">PARTS </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Normal</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">New</div>
</div>

<div class="row word-style table-border">
  <div class="col-md-1">Tech assistance</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">IOT </div>
  <div class="col-md-1">Normal</div>
  <div class="col-md-1">New</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! just one problem. If the text is "Closed Case" and I wanna hide only those with just "Closed" and not "Closed Case" , is it still possible? Right now it's also hiding those with "Closed Case"  @Shree

Comment: I really dont get you. Can you provide some more details about 'Close Case' and where it appear ?